# Fedora apache wsgi python oracle

Tags: python, apache, oracle11g, fedora, wsgi

I'm trying to setup httpd + mod_wsgi(python). Everything works except:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading cx_Oracle module: libclntsh.so.11.1:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now I know about `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables. They are written in /etc/profile.d. And even more so I do have libclntsh.so.11.1 configured in ldconfig paths. And I have a `SetEnv` in virtualhost which I believe has no effect on mod_wsgi whatsoever. Anyone had same issue?

I should also point out that in Ubuntu you can simply put `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `/etc/apache2/envvars` and that should do the trick whereas in Fedora passing environment variable to apache is far more hideous.

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as it can be tricky with certain Apache installations to set it properly as the `envvars` file is ignored.

Instead of relying unjust  that, when you install cx_Oracle, set the `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable to be the location of the library directory holding the Oracle shared libraries.

For example:

LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/oracle/lib pip install cx_Oracle

This will cause the library directory to be embedded in the cx_Oracle C extension and it will be automatically found at runtime without needing to later set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: But if I run django server from user with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set then it works with no errors.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling cx_Oracle with LD_RUN_PATH set as described? Just make sure you use the correct library directory for where Oracle shared libraries are installed.